# How to pop up a new window indirectly when shown a message box when clicking submit button

Tags: javascript

I have problem with how to pop up a new window when I click the submit button.
I have the following code so far:

```
<form action="printstockin.php" name="sumary" method="post"
 onsubmit="return confirm(
       'Are you sure you want to clear this sale? All items will cleared.')" >
```

This code shows an alert box with yes and no options. I want that when I click yes it should pop up a new window. I tried  different things but can't get what exactly i want.

Comment: show us what have you tried. and please don't mix html with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Just put

```
target="_blank"
```

attribute to your form tag:

```
<form action="printstockin.php" name="sumary" method="post" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to clear this sale? All items will cleared.')" target="_blank">
```

Comment: I TRIED THIS CODE sir  BUT IT DOESN'T  POP UP WINDOW. IT OPEN NEW WINDOW. WHAT i am looking for is to pop up window.

Answer (score 0):

onsubmit =" if (confirm('Are you sure you want to clear this sale? All items will cleared.'))window.open(URL,name,specs,replace)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

script-

```
function disp_confirm()
{
 var r=confirm("Are you sure you want to clear this sale? All items will cleared.?")
 if (r==true)
 {
   window.open("http://www.google.com")
 }
 else
 {
  return false;
 }
}
```

HTML -

```
<form action="printstockin.php" name="sumary" method="post" onsubmit="disp_confirm()" >
```